# Using SSM to install CodeDeploy Agent in all new created instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to install the [CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) Agent on all new instances at boot time via [SMM](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/) (AWS Simply System Manager), for example only on instances with the **tag** `managed`

Is this possible currently with SMM or it is only to trigger an action on existing instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ASG life cycle hook to run your SSM document on launch.
More info on exactly how to put this together is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/run-code-before-terminating-an-ec2-auto-scaling-instance/)

TL;DR

1. create SSM document that executes required commands.
2. Create an ASG life cycle hook for an EC2 launch event. (cli or cloud formation)
3. Ensure IAM permissions on EC2 instance grant access to SSM and the document.
4. Launch an instance

For outside of an ASG, you would need to build a bit of a custom solution.

1. Create a lambda that is triggered every time an instance launches. (this requires creating a filter on cloud watch events looking for `RunInstances` event.)
2. The lambda checks the instance tags, if it finds the one you want it makes a call to SSM to execute the document.

Comment: is there a way to do this without an autoscaling group? I could create a custom AMI including `codedploy` and simplify all this but wondering if there are alternatives or ways to do "anything" when the node gets registered, something like with `saltstack` like the first-time action to bootstrap the node.

Comment: @nbari there are two things you can be sure happen when an instance boots up for the first time. It's user data gets run, and the EC2 launch instance API gets called. 
You can trigger a lambda off of the API call for launch EC2 but short of that there is no account tide solution atm.

Comment: by using the `State Manager` and scheduling a task seems to work, the problem I have is that is not consistent, not always is installed so I think that to be safe I will need to add it in the Metadata